# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

when i execute this query i get 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column'  what is the error?

```
    public Cursor Getupdate(String rid) throws SQLException 
        {

Cursor m1Cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM  Meeting   where meet="+rid , null);
    if (m1Cursor != null) {           
        if(m1Cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {

             m1Cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
    }
 return m1Cursor;
}
```

**logcat**

```
05-28 01:22:27.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 01:22:27.999: E/AndroidRuntime(1411): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ttyuhomk: , while compiling: SELECT _id FROM  Meeting where meet=rage
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For string data type always use quotes like this **'"+rid+"'"** since rid is String you get error.

You should use **+rid** only if rid is int.

Answer (score 20):

you need to use apostrophe(') in Where clause checking.. like

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM  Meeting   where meet='"+rid+"'" , null);
```

Comment: well shown. Now what if rid was an int data type? would i write it as "SELECT _id FROM  Meeting   where meet= " + rid

Answer (score 8):

You can also use like this.

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM  Meeting   where meet=?" ,
            new String [] {rid});
```

This will also solve for SQL injection problem.

Comment: `?` args are good, there just isn't an overload of `String.valueOf(String)`

Comment: Oh! Sorry. Actually, it's seems to be like this db.rawQuery("SELECT _id FROM  Meeting   where meet=?" , new String [] {rid}); Thank for your point out to my code.

Comment: Great answer. Just need some explanation about how it can help to solve for SQL injection problem

Comment: By using parameterized query, it will safe against the sql injection attack. For example, in your code your query may look like "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ' " + txtEmail + "' AND password = '" + txtPassword + "'"; when user passed the value of txtPassword as follow. (a' or 'a'='a) your query will look like SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'someemail@somedomain.com' AND password = 'a' or 'a'='a' will return entire table even the password is not correct and user may passed the login with this kind of injection.

Answer (score 5):

Or, better yet, use a PreparedStatement and bind your variables.  It'll escape strings and dates properly for you.  It'll also help with SQL injection problems.

Answer (score 0):

#### Just use single quotes (`'<YOUR_ID_TO_MATCH_WITH>'`)

In case the above answers are still unclear, just use single quotes to surround the where clause.

Eg: `db.update(TABLE_USER,contentValues, "$KEY_TOKEN='${token}'",null)`

Notice the quotes in `'$token'`. That's just it!