# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: place (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Tags: android-studio, android-edittext, android-sqlite, multiple-columns

when I run my application it shows no such column. I want to store and display an event in my application. I have added a new data (place) to the previous one I had which worked. But with this new entry, everything collapse. How can I please solve it.
Thanks in advance

```
public class DbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "create table " + DBStructure.EVENT_TABLE_NAME + "( " + DBStructure.ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + DBStructure.EVENT+ " TEXT, " + DBStructure.TIME + " TEXT, " + DBStructure.DATE+ " TEXT, " + DBStructure.MONTH+ " TEXT, " + DBStructure.PLACE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + DBStructure.YEAR+ " TEXT);"; private static final String DROP_EVENTS_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBStructure.EVENT_TABLE_NAME;


public DbOpenHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DBStructure.DB_NAME, null, DBStructure.DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    //if(newVersion>oldVersion)
        db.execSQL(DROP_EVENTS_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);


}

public void SaveEvent (String event, String place, String time, String date, String month, String year, SQLiteDatabase database) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DBStructure.EVENT, event);
    contentValues.put(DBStructure.PLACE, place);
    contentValues.put(DBStructure.TIME, time);
    contentValues.put(DBStructure.DATE, date);
    contentValues.put(DBStructure.MONTH, month);
    contentValues.put(DBStructure.YEAR, year);
    database.insert(DBStructure.EVENT_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

}

public Cursor ReadEvents (String date, SQLiteDatabase database){
    String [] Projections = {DBStructure.EVENT, DBStructure.PLACE, DBStructure.TIME, DBStructure.DATE, DBStructure.MONTH, DBStructure.YEAR};
    String Selection = DBStructure.DATE + "=?";
    String [] SelectionArgs = {date};
    return database.query(DBStructure.EVENT_TABLE_NAME, Projections, Selection, SelectionArgs, null, null, null );
}

public Cursor ReadEventsPerMonth (String month, String year, SQLiteDatabase database){
    String [] Projections = {DBStructure.EVENT, DBStructure.PLACE, DBStructure.TIME, DBStructure.DATE, DBStructure.MONTH, DBStructure.YEAR};
    String Selection = DBStructure.MONTH + "=? and " + DBStructure.YEAR + "=?";
    String [] SelectionArgs = {month, year};
    return database.query(DBStructure.EVENT_TABLE_NAME, Projections, Selection, SelectionArgs, null, null, null );
}
}
```

```
public class DBStructure {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "EVENTS_DB";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 4;
    public static final String EVENT_TABLE_NAME = "eventsTable";
    public static final String EVENT = "event";
    public static final String PLACE = "place";
    public static final String TIME = "time";
    public static final String DATE = "date";
    public static final String MONTH = "month";
    public static final String YEAR = "year";
    public static final String ID = "ID";
}
```

```
public class CustomCalendarView extends LinearLayout {
    ImageButton PreviousButton, NextButton;
    TextView CurrentDate;
    GridView gridView;
    private static final int MAX_CALENDAR_DAYS=42;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    Context context;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat monthFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat yearFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    SimpleDateFormat eventDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);

    MyGridAdapter myGridAdapter;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    List <Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Events> eventsList = new ArrayList<>();

    DbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;


    public CustomCalendarView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomCalendarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        InitializeLayout ();
        setUpCalendar();

        PreviousButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
                setUpCalendar();
            }
        });

        NextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                setUpCalendar();
            }
        });

// seems to set the clicked day
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                View addView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.add_new_event_layout, null);
                EditText EventName = addView.findViewById(R.id.event_name);
                EditText WhenWhere = addView.findViewById(R.id.when_where);
                EditText Place = addView.findViewById(R.id.place);
                TextView EvenTime = addView.findViewById(R.id.event_time);
                ImageButton SetTime = addView.findViewById(R.id.set_event_time);
                Button AddEvent = addView.findViewById(R.id.add_event);

                // this set the time. ie: thi is where the person can choose the time in term of hour...
                SetTime.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog =  new TimePickerDialog(addView.getContext(), androidx.appcompat.R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Dialog, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
                                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
                                c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
                                SimpleDateFormat hFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
                                String event_Time = hFormat.format(c.getTime());
                                EvenTime.setText(event_Time);
                            }
                        }, hours, minutes, false );

                        timePickerDialog.show();
                    }
                });

                final String date = eventDateFormat.format(dates.get(position));
                final String month = monthFormat.format(dates.get(position));
                final String year = yearFormat.format(dates.get(position));

                // this add an event. Notice here in the onclick the SaveEvent constructor which helps save the event added.
                //that SaveEvent can be find set up down there.
                AddEvent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        SaveEvent (EventName.getText().toString(), Place.getText().toString(), EvenTime.getText().toString(), date, month, year );
                        setUpCalendar();
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                builder.setView(addView);
                alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
        // here the event saved gets call and display
        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String date = eventDateFormat.format(dates.get(position));

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                View showView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.show_events_layout, null);

                RecyclerView recyclerView = showView.findViewById(R.id.eventsRv);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(showView.getContext());
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                EventRecyclerAdapter eventRecyclerAdapter = new EventRecyclerAdapter(showView.getContext(), CollectEventByDate(date));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(eventRecyclerAdapter);
                eventRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                builder.setView(showView);
                alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();


                return true;
            }
        });


    }
    private ArrayList<Events> CollectEventByDate (String date){
        ArrayList<Events> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        dbOpenHelper = new DbOpenHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbOpenHelper.ReadEvents(date, database);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String event = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.EVENT));
            String place = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.PLACE));
            String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.TIME));
            String Date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.DATE));
            String month = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.MONTH));
            String Year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.YEAR));
            Events events = new Events(event, place, time, Date, month, Year);
            arrayList.add(events);
        }
        cursor.close();
        dbOpenHelper.close();
        return arrayList;
    }



    public CustomCalendarView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

    }

    // this, save the event and display text saying that the event is saved.
    private void SaveEvent ( String event, String place, String time, String date, String month, String year){
        dbOpenHelper = new DbOpenHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        dbOpenHelper.SaveEvent(event, place, time, date, month, year, database);
        dbOpenHelper.close();
        Toast.makeText(context, "Events Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private void InitializeLayout (){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_layout, this);
        NextButton = view.findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        PreviousButton = view.findViewById(R.id.previousBtn);
        CurrentDate = view.findViewById(R.id.current_date);
        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    }

    private void setUpCalendar(){
        String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        CurrentDate.setText(currentDate);
        dates.clear();
        Calendar monthCalendar = (Calendar) calendar.clone();
        monthCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
        int FirstDaysOfMonth = monthCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)-1;
        monthCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -FirstDaysOfMonth);
        CollectEventsPerMonth(monthFormat.format(calendar.getTime()), yearFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

        while (dates.size() < MAX_CALENDAR_DAYS){
            dates.add(monthCalendar.getTime());
            monthCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        }

        myGridAdapter = new MyGridAdapter(context, dates, calendar, eventsList);
        gridView.setAdapter(myGridAdapter);
    }


        //Here we gave the constructor that reads from our database
        //after setting it here, the CollectEventsPerMonth is put in setUpCalendar

    private void CollectEventsPerMonth (String Month, String year){
        eventsList.clear();
        dbOpenHelper = new DbOpenHelper(context);
        Cursor cursor;
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
         cursor = dbOpenHelper.ReadEventsPerMonth(Month, year, database);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String event = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.EVENT));
            String place = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.PLACE));
            String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.TIME));
            String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.DATE));
            String month = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.MONTH));
            String Year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBStructure.YEAR));
            Events events = new Events(event, place, time, date, month, Year);
            eventsList.add(events);
        }
        cursor.close();
        dbOpenHelper.close();
    }
}
```

and this is the error I am getting:

> 2023-01-10 15:29:27.408 4603-4603/? E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: place (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT event, place, time, date, month, year FROM eventsTable WHERE month=? and year=?
>          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1045)
>          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:652)
>          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
>          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
>          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
>          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
>          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1392)
>          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1263)
>          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1431)
>          at com.example.android.calendarpoubelle.DbOpenHelper.ReadEventsPerMonth(DbOpenHelper.java:60)
>          at com.example.android.calendarpoubelle.CustomCalendarView.CollectEventsPerMonth(CustomCalendarView.java:243)
>          at com.example.android.calendarpoubelle.CustomCalendarView.setUpCalendar(CustomCalendarView.java:222)
>          at com.example.android.calendarpoubelle.CustomCalendarView.(CustomCalendarView.java:61)
>           ... 28 more
>  2023-01-10 15:29:30.676 14877-15754/system_process E/TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
>  2023-01-10 15:29:40.483 476-476/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
>  2023-01-10 15:29:40.483 476-476/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
>  2023-01-10 15:29:42.603 3276-4261/com.google.android.gms E/WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
>  2023-01-10 15:29:57.838 214-613/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
>  2023-01-10 15:29:57.844 214-613/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
>  2023-01-10 15:30:16.639 483-483/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
>  2023-01-10 15:30:16.639 483-483/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
>  2023-01-10 15:30:40.517 476-476/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
>  2023-01-10 15:30:40.517 476-476/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820106/android-database-sqlite-sqliteexception-no-such-column) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441927/android-sqlite-issue-table-has-no-column-named

Comment: NO, it does'nt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have omitted a space between ID and INTEGER the type thus the column name becomes IDINTEGER, which in turn results in the table not being created as AUTOINCREMENT must be for a column that has INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.

Correcting that error, for a fresh install then the `ReadEventsPerMonth` method works fine.

As such the issue, as you are not seeing the error:-

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: create table eventsTable( IDINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, event TEXT, time TEXT, date TEXT, month TEXT, place TEXT NOT NULL, year TEXT);
```

is virtually certainly because the table exists in it's old form and that the **place** column does not exist.

The reason is very likely that you have added the place column (and perhaps others) and amended the **CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE** value accordingly. However, this on it's own will not introduce the changes as the **onCreate** method only runs once in the lifetime of the database (an it appears to have been created already).

**How to Fix**

1. Use (to add the required space between ID and INTEGER)

:-

```
private static final String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "create table " + DBStructure.EVENT_TABLE_NAME + "( " + DBStructure.ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + DBStructure.EVENT+ " TEXT, " + DBStructure.TIME + " TEXT, " + DBStructure.DATE+ " TEXT, " + DBStructure.MONTH+ " TEXT, " + DBStructure.PLACE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + DBStructure.YEAR+ " TEXT);"; private static final String DROP_EVENTS_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DBStructure.EVENT_TABLE_NAME;
```

2. If there is no critical data in the database then you can simply uninstall the database and rerun the App. The **data in the database will be wiped**.
3. (instead of 2). If you do have critical data then you can use the **onUpdate** method to keep the existing data but adding the new column(s) (perhaps with a default value (not needed as they would be null as you do not have the NOT NULL constraint)). The following is an example (see the comments)

:-

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(newVersion>oldVersion && oldVersion == 4) {
        /* The columns in the original table before the added columns */
        String existing_columns = DBStructure.ID + "," + DBStructure.EVENT + "," + DBStructure.TIME + "," + DBStructure.DATE + "," + DBStructure.MONTH + "," + DBStructure.YEAR;
        /* a new name for the original table so that the new table can be named with the name to be used */
        String original = "original_" + DBStructure.EVENT_TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + DBStructure.EVENT_TABLE_NAME + " RENAME TO " + original); /* rename the original table */
        onCreate(db); /* call the onCreate method to create the new table */
        db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + DBStructure.EVENT_TABLE_NAME +
                /* The columns to be inserted i.e. original columns (existing_columns) and the new column(s) being added */
                "(" + existing_columns + "," + DBStructure.PLACE + ") " +
                /* Using an INSERT SELECT to get the existing data */
                "SELECT " +
                /* The existing columns */
                existing_columns +
                /* and literal value(s) for the added column(s) (just the one in this example ) */
                /*comma required before each new column and a suitable value for the new column */
                 ",'new place' FROM " + original);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + original); /* should have no need for the original (renamed) table so drop it */
    }
}
```

- **NOTE** in conjunction with using    `public static final int DB_VERSION = 5;` (i.e. from version 4 to version 5)
- **NOTE** The above, as it is, is ONLY for adding the **place** column, it would have to be amended to suit another column or other columns.